# How I can estimate a yearly probability in R?

Tags: r

I want to estimate the yearly probability of drug expenditure increase by the proportion
of years where the expenditure was higher than the year before, following the fact that a company wants to know how to increase its drug expenditure in at least 4 of the 5 following consecutive years, in order to assess the investing opportunities.

A snapshot of my data has the above form:

```
Time <- range(1970: 2015)

Healthxp <- c(28.113,   28.275, 27.629, 27.547, 26.779, 21.886, 18.880, 18.301, 17.789, 17.386, 17.374, 16.044, 15.400, 15.594, 14.967, 15.684, 15.708, 15.952, 16.479, 16.231, 15.520, 15.597, 16.282, 17.445, 17.459, 18.068, 17.119, 17.497, 17.130, 17.098, 17.026, 16.501, 16.676, 16.407, 15.792, 15.677, 15.345, 14.599, 14.273, 13.851, 14.209)

pc_gd <- c(1.078,   1.109,  1.126,  1.200,  1.183,  1.208,  1.081,  1.133,  1.135,  1.106,  1.068,  1.053,  1.045,  1.084,  1.017,  1.074,  1.102,  1.136,  1.174,  1.147,  1.103,  1.157,  1.237,  1.347,  1.313,  1.351,  1.327,  1.332,  1.557,  1.557,  1.536,  1.472,  1.493,  1.532,  1.590,  1.555,  1.547,  1.487,  1.480,  1.440,  1.489)

usd_cap <- c(41.918,    46.908, 52.105, 61.916, 69.147, 75.852, 75.524, 84.525, 93.107, 100.444,    110.325,    118.541,    125.806,    136.098,    135.461,    149.94,6    159.833,    172.740,    192.778,    201.741,    206.956 227.548 251.603 276.698 283.434 304.259,    303.867,    318.442,    483.535,    502.408,    512.107,    521.218,    550.120,    584.310,    605.096,    623.970,    638.092,    629.735,    642.958,    644.954,    678.971)

total_exp <- c(404.74,  453.75, 506.00, 603.17, 675.73, 743.40, 741.51, 830.91, 916.13, 989.21, 1087.72,    1168.69,    1239.98,    1341.32,    1335.02,    1478.21,    1576.24,    1704.98,    1908.82,    2004.84,    2062.81,    2276.50,    2527.39,    2790.35,    2867.11,    3084.22,    3086.27,    3242.14,    5017.22,    5235.66,    5366.17,    5497.79,    5845.41,    6257.94,    6532.91,    6798.52,    7049.48,    7007.85,    7190.08,    7229.33,    7654.85)
```

I am using R. I was thinking to use find the difference between the year with the most expenditure from the previous one, and then calculate a `dbinom`. Is this correct?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.